# CSS More than 1 background with gradients in a button

Tags: html, css, button, gradient

so i have a button and it has a gradient. that button is able to work in all browsers due to all its prefixes. But i want to add one more background which is a small play image. The thing is i can't seem to center that button and go on top of all the gradients. It won't even show? Take a look at the code below:

```css
#mcodebtn {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://s3.amazonaws.com/content.newsok.com/newsok/images/video-icon-play.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0px;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
.form1btn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 103px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 46px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form1btn">
  <input type="button" id="mcodebtn" value="">
</div>
```

Basically what i'm trying to do is add that play image to the center of the button while still keeping the gradient background and all the other browser prefixes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want add one more image or gradient?

Comment: Just one more image, but also keep all those gradients.

Comment: do you know about multiple background syntax ? :such like  `background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9), url(http://s3.amazonaws.com/content.newsok.com/newsok/images/video-icon-play.png);`

Comment: Yes @GCyrillus i have tried that but it didn't work for some reason. I'm not sure if multiple background syntax works well with browser prefixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the result you are looking for?

```css
#mcodebtn {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0px;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
.form1btn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 103px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 46px;
 
}

.imgbutton{
position: relative;
display: block;
height: 32px;
width: 32px;
margin: 8px auto 0 auto; 

   

}
```

```html
<div class="form1btn">
  <input type="button" id="mcodebtn" value=""><img class="imgbutton" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/content.newsok.com/newsok/images/video-icon-play.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: Yes! thats exactly what i needed. I was able to figure out an alternative. Basically adding another division and adding the image. Setting the pointer event to none and it also did the trick xD

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the image with your gradient and then apply both images to your `<input>`. Like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/juu1wbba) one.

```css
#mcodebtn {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://i40.tinypic.com/fcnu2x.png), url(http://www.blirk.net/wallpapers/preview/gradient-wallpaper-1.jpg) ;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0px;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
.form1btn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 103px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 46px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form1btn">
  <input type="button" value="" id="mcodebtn">
</div>
```